# How can I replace no digit character with space character?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I'd like to replace every **not digit** character in string with a *space character*.

For ex.: `"123X456Y78W9" -> "123 456 78 9"`

Only resolution that I worked out is here:

```
string input = "123X456Y78W9";
string output = "";

foreach (char c in input)
    if (c in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0))
        output += c;
    else
        output += ' ';
```

Is there are any simpler resolution?

Comment: Which encoding? ASCII or UTF8 or ...

Comment: Using a regexp might be simpler, but most likely less performance (except the regexp-implementation is very smart and detects that this is a very special and simple regexp than can be implemented by e.g. looking Lookup-table while iteration the String (can even be done inplace if a mutable datatype is used))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace()` with a character class of all non digits.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", @" ");
```

Comment: You can put a shorter pattern `@"\D"` instead of  `@"[^\d]"`, since `\D` means *not a digit*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: True. I forgot about that. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: Side note: `@"\D"` means not any *unicode digits* (not only `0..9` but many others, like persian ones - `۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹`). If only `0..9` should be preserved, add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` as the last parameter: `Regex.Replace(input, @"\D", " ", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);`

Answer (score 4):

*Linq* is an alternative to *regular expressions*:

```
string input = "123X456Y78W9"; 

string output = string.Concat(input.Select(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c : ' '));
```

Or if you want to preserve *all unicode digits* (say, *persian* ones - `۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹`)

```
string output = string.Concat(input.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c) ? c : ' '));
```

Comment: Linq is a *more readable* alternative to regular expressions - as proved by the difference between upper and lower case d in the sticky bit's answer.